# Azure Table Update Concurrency Issue

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage

I am trying to update a user credit / count information against each transaction.  If we hit more than 2/4 transaction per second the update below is not updating the counts / user credit information.

Two Issues basically.

1. Update not happening sometime with NO, Error Message.
2. Update failing with Error message: 412: Fail: Code: 412 Value: Precondition Failed details (if any): UpdateConditionNotSatisfied The update condition specified in the request was not satisfied. RequestId:1beb3fa9-9ad2-46f7-b8ee-af3a09300db7 Time:2013-06-09T16:12:17.6797130Z .

I am doing a prototype for Migration from RDMBS to NoSQL using Azure for a [SMS API](http://www.innovativetxt.com). Not sure why such thing happening.

Code Paste below

```
public function update_credit_to_azure_table () {
  // Create table REST proxy.
  $tableRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()
    ->createTableService($this->connectionString);

  $result = $tableRestProxy->getEntity("tblapilogin",  $this->apiusr , $this->apiusr);
  $entity = $result->getEntity();

  $new_api_balance = $this->global_api_credit - $this->credittodeduct;
  $credit_used = $this->api_credit_used + $this->credittodeduct;

  $entity->setPropertyValue("global_api_credit", $new_api_balance); //Update Balance.
  $entity->setPropertyValue("api_credit_used", $credit_used); //credit used Updated .

  try {
    $tableRestProxy->updateEntity("tblapilogin", $entity);

    echo "<br>New Blance is: " . $new_api_balance;
    echo "<br>credit_used  is: " . $credit_used;
  }
  catch(ServiceException $e) {
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
  }
}
```

**The update function with optimistic concurrency is kind of major test here.**

Comment: The first should basically not happen. The second is afaict normal, if you're trying to update an entity but it has already been (simultaneously) updated by another transaction, an updateEntity will fail and you'll have to retry.

Comment: It was like less than 10 transaction per second even the 2nd behavior shall not happen.  I believe  azure table storage claim more than 400 transaction per second.  ( Not sure if Update is very limited).  I heard Etag thingy is that related here and how to apply that with API calls if that needs to be controled?

Comment: I may be wrong since I've not read up on the limits, but I believe the 400 per second is per partition for batch updates, not for single updates on a single entity.

Comment: Also, [this link](http://robertgreiner.com/2012/06/why-is-azure-table-storage-so-slow/) may help.

Comment: i turned off nagging still i don't see any increase in performance... I am trying less than 10 update per second on same entity per seconds.  ( I have one entity in table with row key and partition key as "as234q243"  its just one entity in table with same row and partition key) and such horrible performance.  Not sure if table storage is built for inserts only.

Comment: I've only used it "read heavy" and fairly well partitioned, and for that it seems to work very well. Have not tried it for heavy writes to a single entity though. Since it seems to work best with many partitions even for read, I suspect hammering a single partition/entity with writes may not perform as well as it could.

Comment: As noted elsewhere, the 412's are expected. The failures with no error shouldn't happen. I would suspect a bug in the client library. You could try to repro the bug from your local machine with an artificial test, while running a debugging HTTP proxy. That might help nail down the problem.

Comment: The 412 error on more than 3-5 transcation per second is very strange to me.

Comment: I looked at the stats of the Azure Monitor it says "Client Other Error Percentage" is 20%.  I am having 1 VM so CPU is all free.  probably issue is with Update or PHP SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert in PHP but looking at the source code on [`Github`](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-php/blob/master/WindowsAzure/Table/TableRestProxy.php), I found that `updateEntity` function always forces the use of `ETag` i.e. the function forces a conditional update:

```
public function updateEntity($table, $entity, $options = null)
    {
        return $this->_putOrMergeEntityImpl(
            $table,
            $entity,
            Resources::HTTP_PUT,
            true, 
            $options
        );
    }
```

Based on the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179427.aspx):

> If the entity's ETag differs from that specified with the update
>   request, the update operation fails with status code 412 (Precondition
>   Failed). This error indicates that the entity has been changed on the
>   server since it was retrieved. To resolve this error, retrieve the
>   entity again and reissue the request.
>
> To force an unconditional update operation, set the value of the
>   If-Match header to the wildcard character (*) on the request. Passing
>   this value to the operation will override the default optimistic
>   concurrency and ignore any mismatch in ETag values.

If the Etag value does not match, you'll get a 412 error which you're getting.

I would suggest using `insertOrReplaceEntity` operation instead of `updateEntity` operation as it would create an entity if it does not exist otherwise it will update it. Also looking at the code, this one does not make use of `ETag`.

```
public function insertOrReplaceEntity($table, $entity, $options = null)
    {
        return $this->_putOrMergeEntityImpl(
            $table,
            $entity,
            Resources::HTTP_PUT,
            false, 
            $options
        );
    }
```

Notice the 4th parameter in both functions. This is the one which forces the use of ETag. In `updateEntity` it is set to `true` while in `insertOrReplaceEntity` it is set to `false`.

Comment: Many thanks for detailed response. The update function with optimistic concurrency is kind of major need to update User Balance/credit/money left.   I am quiet shocked unable to pinpoint whats going wrong as Update 5 or 10 hits per second shall not behave like this.

Answer (score 0):

Its the same problem as explained by Steve in one of his episode.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Cloud+Cover/Cloud-Cover-Episode-43-Scalable-Counters-with-Windows-Azure

If you are doing 1 read, write operation per second on same entity it will work with no Etag failuer.  Otherwise you have build your own smart logic around this.

Another Useful Resource is:

[How to build a highly scaleable global counter in Azure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13578225/how-to-build-a-highly-scaleable-global-counter-in-azure)